# Searching two things

Tags: python, string, search

I am using `re` and would like to search a string between two strings. My problem is the string that I would like to search may end with either newline(\n) or another string. So what I want to do is if it is newline or another string it should give me back the string. The reason why I want to do that is some of my documents are created wrong in a way that it does not have new line, so I have to get the text until newline and then check if it has the corresponding string.

I have tried this:

```
recipients = re.search('Recipients:(.*)\n', body)
reciBody = re.search('(.*)Notes', recipients.group(1).encode("utf-8"))
```

Later on I am trying to split this by using:

```
recipientsList = reciBody.group(1).encode("utf-8").split(',')
```

The problem is I am getting this error if there is no corresponding string:

```
        recipientsList = reciBody.group(1).encode("utf-8").split(',')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

What other ways can I use? Or how can I handle this errror?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming nothing needs to be done if the group isn't found. Simplest is to just skip the error.

```
try:
    recipientsList = reciBody.group(1).encode("utf-8").split(',')
except AttributeError:
    pass # nothing needs to be done
```

Instead of `pass` you may need to set `recipientsList` to something else